# Standard deviation of a ratio and calculation of weight

Tags: variance, central-limit-theorem, weights, weighted-mean

I have several "skilled" and "unskilled" wage observations for a number of countries, and would like to construct a single skilled-unskilled wage premium by country as the ratio of the simple average of skilled and unskilled wages.

Since individual wage reports are noisy, I would like to give more weight to wage premium estimates that have a reasonable number of observations in *both* categories in subsequent analyses. What would be a reasonable way of calculating the weight for each wage premium estimate? We can assume that the error terms of skilled and unskilled wage reports from a country are independently and normally distributed.

Some more considerations: If it was just one average wage, I think the central limit theorem suggests to weight each average by the square root of the number of observations that gave rise to it since Sd^(meanwage)=Sd^(individ. wage)/sqrt(N), and hence the standard deviation of the average decreases in the square root of N.

What is the analogous formula for Sd^(meanwage_skilled/meanwage_unskilled)? And given that it will likely be a little more complicated and involve the number of both skilled and unskilled wage observations, any suggestions on how to translate this into a weight for the wage premium?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to aggregate your data into an array. Have the first column represent the log of the weight and the second column represent a binary coding of 1: skilled vs. 0: unskilled labor status. Fit a regression model with log-weight as the outcome and labor status as the exposure. Take the coefficient and upper and lower 95% confidence limits and exponentiate all 3. These are interpreted as the ratio of weight comparing skilled to unskilled laborers. The p-value corresponds to the significance test that this ratio has a null value of 1 (no difference).

The central limit theorem doesn't apply to the ratio because you aren't sampling and thus averaging the ratios themselves. The "statistics" which are accruing are the skilled/unskilled laborer means. The $\delta$-method is another option for aggregating those data. Using the Jacobian matrix:

$$ \text{Var}\left( \bar{W}_{s}/\bar{W}_{u} \right) \approx 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1/\bar{W}_u \\ -(\bar{W}_s/\bar{W}_u)^2 \end{array} \right]^T 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc} \text{Var} \left( \bar{W}_{s} \right) & 0 \\
0 & \text{Var} \left( \bar{W}_{u} \right) \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1/\bar{W}_u \\ -(\bar{W}_s/\bar{W}_u)^2 \end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: Thanks Adam! What would be the dependent variable in the regression you suggest in the first part of your answer? Note that I do not have any weights- I am thinking about how to calculate a resonable weight for wage premium estimates that are based on different numbers of skilled and unskilled wages, and was hoping to use the standard deviation of the wage premium for guidance. But looking at the analytical expression from the delate method, I am not quite sure how to translate it into a weight.